# Dynamically arrange data of jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, dynamic-columns

I am not able to arrange the cell data dynamically with respect to customize column. In the cell collection I want to arrange the cell values as per the column sequence.
The Column are :[COLUMN10, COLUMN3, COLUMN1, COLUMN7, COLUMN9](those are coming from database) and the column sequence will be dynamically change. In that case I am not able to arrange the cell value dynamically with respect the sequence of the column. Please find my snapshot of the code, which I am using in my code.

```
jsonData = new
                {
                    total = totalPages,
                    page,
                    records = totalRecords,
                    rows = (
                        from Details in ListData
                        select new
                        {
                            i = 1,
                            cell = new string[] { 
                                              Details.COLUMN10,
                                              Details.COLUMN3,
                                              Details.COLUMN1,
                                              Details.COLUMN7,
                                              Details.COLUMN9
                                }
                        }
                        ).ToArray()
```

Please guide and let me know the flow through which I can proceed.

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you need. You wrote about "arrangement the cell values". What you mean? There are horizontal and vertical arrangement for example. You wrote "the column sequence will be dynamically change". Who changes the columns (the user, the backend code and so on)? What will be changes: the order, the type of data, the alignment (from left aligned to right alignment) and so on? The code which you posted is probably incorrect too. What is `i = 1`? Do you mean `id` instead if `i`? Why all items have the same id? The ids have to be unique? Where is your JavaScript code?

Comment: Let me explain the query more clear.
1. In table there are 10 columns i.e COLUMN1,COLUMN2,...,COLUMN10.
2. User will select which column will be display in the grid.Along with the order of the columns will be selected by user. For example user had selected as COLUMN3,COLUMN10,COLUMN5,COLUMN6,COLUMN1.
3. This sequence is saved in database based on user. 
4. I have arranged the grid header model and header name according to sequence ie. COLUMN3,COLUMN10,COLUMN5,COLUMN6,COLUMN1.
5. But I need to add cell data according to column sequence. According to me the cell data arranged in above linq query

Comment: I'd recommend you to return just `ListData.ToArray()`. The returned data will be `[{"COLUMN1":"v1_1","COLUMN2":"v1_2",...,"COLUMN10":"v1_10"}, {"COLUMN1":"v2_1","COLUMN2":"v2_2",...,"COLUMN10":"v2_10"}, ...]` and to use `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid. At the next step you can change the format of returned data to `{"columnVisibility":{"COLUMN1":true, "COLUMN2": false,,,, "COLUMN10": true}, "rows":[{"COLUMN1":"v1_1","COLUMN2":"v1_2",...,"COLUMN10":"v1_10"}, {"COLUMN1":"v2_1","COLUMN2":"v2_2",...,"COLUMN10":"v2_10"}, ...]}`. You will set the columns hidden before displaying the data.

Comment: I have two cases:
Case 1: I have a pagination. every times it loads the data from database. so not able to set loadonce:true.
Case 2: I have to change the sequence order of column like as Column3 then  Column1 and Then Column4.

Comment: One can't solve **different cases**  at once. You should start with the most common case. I suggest you to start with `loadonce:true` scenario and implement the next one only if it's really required and after you understand jqGrid better. The first very important question is: how many total rows you need to display (100, 1000, 10000, 1000000 or more)?

Comment: I suggest you to test the performance of **local** sorting, paging and filtering on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) with 4000 rows and 13 columns and [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) with 40000 rows and 13 columns.